# Android CheckBox Select all

Tags: android, checkbox

I am stuck in a scenario. I have a list view with multiple items and a checkbox in all, Now I have implemented a feature when someone presses the select all button, all the list view items checkboxes should be selected and vice versa.

Now I have to implement, after pressing select all, if the user unchecks some of the items from the list items - then THE SELECT ALL BUTTON SHOULD BE AUTOMATICALLY UNCHECKED.

```
 /** Select All checkbox functionality here.. */
        mcbSelectAllContact
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                groupListAdapter = new GroupMemberListAdapter(
                        buttonView.getContext(), isChecked);
                mlvGroupContactList.setAdapter(groupListAdapter);
                if (mcbSelectAllContact.isChecked()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mBooleanArray.length; i++) {
                        mBooleanArray[i] = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mBooleanArray.length; i++) {
                        mBooleanArray[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for all your checkboxes and whenever one is unchecked, change the `mcbSelectAllContact` to be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

I tried get the check boxes from list view and set checked true. I hope this will be help to you

```
 selelctAll_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (listview.getCount() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++) {
                    View view = listview.getChildAt(i);
                    CheckBox check=   (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                    check.setChecked(true);
                }
        }
        }
    });
```